# AREL: Common Table Expression with explicit columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, common-table-expression, arel

The [AREL README](https://github.com/rails/arel) covers CTEs briefly, but doesn't mention how to handle explicit column lists in a CTE.  E.g. a CTE like:

`WITH my_query (col1, col2, col3, col4) AS (
  SELECT a, b, a, b FROM my_table
)`

I was able to generate the above using a convoluted SqlLiteral, but is there a better way?

Example solution:

`cte_table      = Arel::Table.new(:source_qry)
cte_qry        = Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("source_qry (col1, col2, col3, col4)")
user_qry       = Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("(SELECT a, b, a, b FROM my_table)")
cte_table_qry  = Arel::Nodes::As.new(cte_qry, user_qry)
cte_table.project(%w(col1 col2)).with(cte_table_qry)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that Arel does not handle this for now. I do not know how to completely solve this, but can suggest how to improve your solution a little:

```
cte_table = Arel::Table.new(:source_qry)
cte_qry = Arel.sql("source_qry (col1, col2, col3, col4)")

my_table = Arel::Table.new(:my_table)
user_qry = my_table.project(my_table[:a], my_table[:b], my_table[:a], my_table[:b])

cte_table_qry = Arel::Nodes::As.new(cte_qry, user_qry)

cte_table.project(cte_table[:col1], cte_table[:col2]).with(cte_table_qry)
```